# Htaccess Match Random 6 characters, with exceptions?

Tags: apache, codeigniter, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Alright, so I've been trying to wrap my head around (what I believe to be) a simple mod_rewrite case. Maybe it's not, but I'm hoping you can help me with that, Stack Overflow.

So what I want is this: there are several folders that need to be ignored (ie, "css", "js", "bootstrap", etc). If the url string doesn't match those, I want to check if it's a string of exactly six letters and numbers, and redirect that to one url. Otherwise, it gets redirected to another url.

This is what I have:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|bootstrap|phpmyadmin|css|js|font|recaptchalib.php|uploads)/
RewriteRule ^(a-z0-9+){6}$ /index.php/download/index/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

If I take out the middle line, it works fine except I don't get the "match 6 random characters" functionality. With the middle line, I get a 500 error on every page.

Could someone help me out please?

Comment: I am not sure about htaccess, but almost everywhere ranges should be defined like this ([a-z0-9]+)

Comment: If you want an exact 6 characters, you don't need the + near the ranges so it should be something like ([a-z0-9]{6})

Answer (score 0):

You need to repeat the condition. A `RewriteCond` only applies to the immediately following `RewriteRule`. So you're second rule doesn't exclude all those folders in the pattern that you have in your condition. Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|bootstrap|phpmyadmin|css|js|font|recaptchalib.php|uploads)/
RewriteRule ^(a-z0-9+){6}$ /index.php/download/index/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|bootstrap|phpmyadmin|css|js|font|recaptchalib.php|uploads)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

**You should let CodeIgniter handle this.** Keep your .htaccess for routing to the index.php front controller, and use route(s) to handle the URI and where it should go from there.

This is especially true because now ANY six-letter URI is going to be defaulted. What if you have a controller like `example.com/bloggers`? It will always be assumed to be a download item, even if it's a real controller URI.

The "easiest" option (read: option that does not conflict with existing controllers/routes) is to utilize the `404_controller` to check the URI and see if it's a valid download URL. Then you can run the appropriate code.

---

To explain a likely reason why your .htaccess code is not working: your regular expression for matching six alpha-numeric characters is wrong. Here's what you need:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]{6})$
```

This regex can be used as a CodeIgniter route, also, if you go that route (heh). Just remove the `^$` beginning/end characters, as CI puts them there for you.

As mentioned by Jon Lin, you also need to duplicate `RewriteCond` conditionals, as they are only good for one `RewriteRule`. After one, the conditionals reset.